# Ruby execution on Mac OSX huge and weird time difference between 2 directories

Tags: ruby, macos

I am facing a very weird situation on Mac OS X.
This has bee replicated on two Macs (a Macbook and Mac Mini Server).

Essentially I am running the same, identical ruby code in two different directories. In the first directory I have an execution time of 7 seconds and on the second directory 0.191.
There is absolutely no difference among the two.

```
gspider@b1-3 ~£ time ruby  sb2.rb 
#<struct recno=2001, name="Amazon", ticker="MPS", tradeprice=185.5, tradedate="2012-04-        28", quantity=45, totalposition=8347.5>
```

```
real    0m7.775s
user    0m7.160s
sys 0m0.612s


 gspider@b1-3 ~/Sites£ time ruby sb2.rb
 #<struct recno=2001, name="Amazon", ticker="MPS", tradeprice=185.5, tradedate="2012-04-       28", quantity=45, totalposition=8347.5>
```

```
real    0m0.191s
user    0m0.164s
 sys    0m0.023s
```

but there is more. Even a simple ruby script fetching a non existing file behaves different in the two directories: Notice that it is using the same identical ruby version

```
gspider@b1-3 ~£ time ruby sb3.rb
/Users/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/KirbyBase-2.6.1/lib/kirbybase.rb:520:in      `get_table': Table not found! (RuntimeError)
from sb3.rb:8:in `<main>'

real    0m7.885s
user    0m7.240s
sys 0m0.642s


gspider@b1-3 ~/Sites£ time ruby  sb3.rb
/Users/spider/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/KirbyBase-2.6.1/lib/kirbybase.rb:520:in    `get_table': Table not found! (RuntimeError)
from sb3.rb:8:in `<main>'

real    0m0.183s
user    0m0.156s
sys 0m0.023s
```

What can be the cause for this highly erratic behavior ? Again this is the same machine as you can see from the bash tag just 2 different directories. I have been able to replicate the same error on another mac but the "infected" path/directory is different so it just looks like randomly some directories /paths get this ruby slow delayed execution curse.

Comment: What happens if you reverse the order you check the directories? What's the code? So far I'd guess there's some caching going on somewhere.

Comment: Yes, caching is likely. Also, ~/Sites typically contains some files, like index.html. If the script is searching for such a file, maybe it finds it immediately in the ~/Sites directory but has to perform an exhaustive search before giving up in another dir.

Comment: reversing the order returns the same results. In the "cursed" dir it runs always with 5-6 seconds delay

Comment: the file is a simple script to fetch 3 results from a table (a flat file) using KirbyBase (a ruby gem). The file is the same in both directories. Deleting the file/fetching a non existing give the same result as seen above 7.8 sec in one case 0.018 in the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KirkyBase opens all tables ( .tbl files ) in a folder.

If you have more bigger files in some folder and less or smaller files in the other this might explain the difference in time.